# How do I see the enclosing blocks/elements with my keyboard in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2019, I can hover over the dotted lines indicating spacing.
If I keep my mouse still for a second, Visual Studio will display a box showing the enclosing blocks.

[image]

This works and has been very helpful for me while writing C#, TypeScript and HTML (for HTML it shows enclosing elements, not enclosing blocks; also I couldn't get Sass to work).

My question:
How do I, if possible, get this box to display, using just my keyboard? Thank you :)

Comment: Is this giving you some information that you don't think the "headers"/dropdowns at the top of the editor is giving you? I.e. the method definition is shown in the right-most dropdown (the one with the purple box just outside the top-right of your screenshot).

Comment: @Xerillio For HTML, at least, the enclosing elements do not show at the top.

Comment: @Xerillio This also includes `if (var == true) { ` and `foreach (var x in bar) { ` however deep back to the function declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the ability to view the structure, called Show Structure in the menu options. The shortcut for this is...`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+G`

You can see this from the code page's context menu... Right click the code page > Annotation > Show Structure.